# Is there a way to Count a Column and if >1 check Column B if condition is met skip

Tags: sql-server

I am writing a SQL query where I am trying to find any account with a disabled credit card, that does not have a second active card on file. Using a Select Distinct, I can get it down to the individual rows, but I can't figure out how to write the Case. I was thinking I could use a count to count the rows, and if one of the rows was listed as Active, skip the record all together. So if the account number shows up twice, check to see if one of the rows is active, if it is, skip the account.

As I mentioned I can parse out the raw data and pull everything on the account, but the second half eludes me. I am fairly new to SQL and Coding in general.

```
SELECT   DISTINCT    dbo.loanacct.column, 

    CASE dbo.account.status
                 When '0' then 'Active'
         When '1' then 'Closed'
    End AS 'Account Status', 
                  dbo.loanacct.total_past_due_balance,

    Case dbo.card.status
        When '0' then 'Active'
        when '1' then 'Disabled'
        When '2' then 'Expired'
    END AS 'Card Status'
FROM            dbo.loanacct 
Where     Loan_group = 'Group'
         AND dbo.loanacct.status_code = 'Status Code'
     AND dbo.loanacct.total_past_due_balance <> '0.00'
         AND dbo.loanacct.status_code_no = '0'
         OR dbo.loanacct_Card_Status IS NU
```

Current output looks something like this:

```
  Acct# Customer Name Group       Status Code   Acct Status Card Status 
  12345 Name          INSTALLMENT Status        Active      Active 
  12345 NAME          INSTALLMENT Status        Active      Disabled
```

What I would like it to do, is when the above example is true, same account# but there is an active card on file, this account would be skipped and I would get a single line return on the next account # that does not have an active card on file.

```
Acct# Customer Name Group Status   Code   Acct Status Card Status 
54321 Name          INSTALLMENT    Status Active      Disabled
```

Comment: it will be nice if you add some sample data and expected output

Comment: Please show sample data and desired results, these are much more useful than a query that doesn't do what you want. :-)

Comment: Thats odd, I have sample code on there. Let me work on the expected out put.

Comment: Seems like what you are after is a conditional aggregation; which is possible in T-SQL yes.

Comment: @RDBCruzer sample code is important to include in a question.  Sample data and desired output based on that sample data (as text in the question - **not** as a screen shot) are equally important.

Comment: I think I have it now.

Comment: Should the expected results value for `Acct#` not be `12345`? Or are you intentionally reversing it's value?

Comment: I intentionally reversed the value to try and reflect an entry that I want to display. I can see now where that is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this will get you the answer, or if not get you close to it. The aprt you're interesting in is the `CASE` expressions. This also assumes that `54321` is incorrect for the account number, and it should be `12345`. If you are intentionally reversing the value, see the adjacent comment.

```
SELECT Acct#, --REVERSE(Acct#)? See comment
       [Customer Name], --it's actually advised against having spaces, and other special characters, in your object names
       [Group Status],  --as you then are forced to always quote them; and that can "break" things if poorly handled.
       Code,
       [Acct Status],
       CASE COUNT(CASE [Card Status] WHEN 'Disabled' THEN 1 END) > 0 THEN 'Disabled' ELSE 'Active'
FROM ...
GROUP BY Acct#,
         [Customer Name],
         [Group Status], 
         Code,
         [Acct Status];
```

I haven't included the `FROM`, and `WHERE`, here, but you should have enough to complete.